# How do I join string set into a single string with positions prepended?

Tags: clojure

Assume I have this

```
(def base ["one" "two" "three"])
```

I want to convert it to:

```
1. one
2. two
3. three
```

(aka `1. one \n2. two \n3. three`)

with `join`, I am not sure I can append a counter before joining:

```
(clojure.string/join " \n" base)
=> "one \ntwo \nthree"
```

and with `doseq` or similar, plus an atom, I do get individual strings but then will have to concatenate later on, something like

```
(def base ["one" "two" "three"])

(def pos (atom 0))

(defn add-pos
  [base]
  (for [b base]
    (do 
      (swap! pos inc)
      (str @pos ". " b))))

(let [pos-base (add-pos base)]
  (clojure.string/join " \n" pos-base))

=> "1. one \n2. two \n3. three"
```

While it works, I don't know if using an atom with a `for` statement is he best way to do this, it doesn't look very clojure-esque.

Is there a better way to do this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a job for [keep-indexed](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keep-indexed):

```
user> (keep-indexed #(str (inc %1) ". " %2) ["one" "two" "three"])
("1. one" "2. two" "3. three")
user> (clojure.string/join "\n"
         (keep-indexed 
            #(str (inc %1) ". " %2) 
            ["one" "two" "three"]))
"1. one\n2. two\n3. three"
```

Comment: Great! Looks like clojure has functions for pretty much most things and my biggest problem is finding / discovering those functions!

Comment: in addition to SO, you could sign up for 4clojure and then look at the solutions that others have done as you go -- useful for API discovery of core Clojure and seeing when/where certain functions can be used

Comment: The use of `keep-indexed` runs a logical truth check on each value returned by the lambda passed to it to eventually leave it out. This check is entirely useless in this case and thus unnecessary overhead. `map-indexed` would suffice.

Answer (score 3):

A minor alternative to schaueho's keep-indexed would be [map-indexed](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map-indexed) (spotting a pattern?)

```
(def base ["one" "two" "three"])

(defn numbered-list [s]
  (->> s
       (map-indexed #(str (inc %1) ". " %2))
       (interpose \newline)
       (apply str)))

(numbered-list base) ; => "1. one\n2. two\n3. three"
```

Answer (score 3):

Clearly a job for [interleave](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/interleave).

```
(->> (interleave (rest (range)) (repeat ". ") base (repeat " \n"))
     (apply str))

;-> "1. one \n2. two \n3. three \n"
```